# jQuery - how to select a href to toggle hide and show?

Tags: jquery

Totally new to jQuery. I'm trying to select the a href tags that hide and show the div contents. I understand how to use the toggle, but not sure how to properly select the a href tags to initiate the toggle of the div tags. I have to be able to select the a href tag without changing the html source code. But when I set it to the div within the part3 id, all divs outside of the id part3 are also selected that are within the document are altered. Any help is appreciated. Thanks community.

```
    <script type = "text/javascript">   
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $("#part3 h4").click(function () {
            $(this).next().toggle();
        });

        $("#part3 h4").mouseover(function() {
            $(this).addClass("faq over");
        });

        $("#part3 h4").mouseout(function() {
            $(this).removeClass("faq over");
        });

        $("#part3 > a:first").click(function() {
            $("div").show(); // not sure how to access each a href tag
        });
    });
</script>

<div id="part3">
    <h2>3: FAQ Hide/Show Demo</h2>
    <a href="#">Show All</a> | <a href="#">Hide All</a>
    <div class="faq">          
            <h4>1.How much does it cost? </h4>
            <div>
                <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit,
                 sed diam nonummy nibh euismod tincidunt ut laoreet dolore magna 
                  <strong>aliquam</strong> erat volutpat. Ut wisi enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud 
                 exerci tation ullamcorper suscipit lobortis nisl ut aliquip ex ea 
                 commodo consequat. </p>
            </div>
            <h4>2.What is the meaning of life? </h4>
            <div>
                <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit,
                 sed diam nonummy nibh euismod tincidunt<strong> ut laoreet dolore</strong> magna 
                 a<em>liquam erat volutpat. Ut wisi e</em>nim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud 
                 exerci tation ullamcorper suscipit lobortis nisl ut aliquip ex ea 
                 commodo consequat. </p>
            </div>
            <h4>3.Why is the sky blue?</h4>
            <div>
                <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit,
                 sed diam nonummy nibh euismod tincidunt ut laoreet <strong>dolore magna 
                 aliquam</strong> erat volutpat. Ut wisi enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud 
                 exerci tation ullamcorper suscipit lobortis nisl ut aliquip ex ea 
                 commodo consequat. </p>
            </div>
            <h4>4.Why is the real cost of money?</h4>
            <div>
                <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit,
                 sed diam nonummy nibh euismod tincidunt ut laoreet dolore magna 
                 aliquam erat volutpat. <strong>Ut wisi enim ad minim</strong> veniam, quis nostrud 
                 exerci tation ullamcorper suscipit lobortis nisl ut aliquip ex ea 
                 commodo consequat. </p>
            </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
   //Here you get the first anchor and bind the handler to it
   var $first = $("#part3 > a:first").click(function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        $(this).siblings('.faq').show(); // not sure how to access each a href tag
    });
    //With the first one, just select the next one
     $first.next('a').click(function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        $(this).siblings('.faq').hide(); // not sure how to access each a href tag
    });
```

**[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/3Ynm2/)**

Or just:

```
   //Or select both of them together and bind a single handler to it
   $("#part3 > a:first").next('a').addBack().click(function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        var $this = $(this);
        //toggle takes a boolean value to determine whether to show or hide, so just pass the inner text of the anchor to it as a conditional expression.
        $this.siblings('.faq').toggle($.trim($this.text()) === 'Show All'); // not sure how to access each a href tag
    });
```

**[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/SptLT/)**

Comment: i appreciate the help, i edited a bit but i got it to work. thanks a bunch

Comment: @khmer2040 You are welcome. Just added some comments incase you need it,

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
$("#part3 a").click(function() {
          var ind = $( this ).index();
            if(ind === 1)
              $(".faq div").show();
            else if(ind === 2)
              $(".faq div").hide(); 
        });
```

[<kbd>**Live Demo**</kbd>](http://jsbin.com/iseWabA/1/edit)

Comment: thanks for the help, i slightly modified your answer to get it to work how i need it to work, lol much appreciated

Comment: Be careful with `$("#part3 a")` selector if there is an anchor inside the div it will bind the event to that as well unwantedly. You can probably use `.children('a')` or `$("#part3 > a")` which would be more safer IMHO.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `$('.faq').show();` and `$('.faq').hide();`

```
 <a href="#" onclick="$('.faq').show();">Show All</a> | <a href="#" onclick="$('.faq').hide();">Hide All</a>
```

Comment: i appreciate the quick response but I am not able to modify the html code within the a href tag. i was wondering how i would access it directly through jqeury